# Table cell selection diagonally, horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple js code for a custom word search table. This is the first time I'm doing this so, I borrowed some code that I found on the web. It doesn't work properly though, while I'm trying to select a cell. Even if try to do this diagonally, horizontally or vertically. The first and  the last cell of the selection are only highlighted( they have the highlighted class). Everything between is not.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>TABLE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700&subset=latin,greek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class=" table ">
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- First Row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>P</td>
                                <td>U</td>
                                <td>Z</td>
                                <td>Z</td>
                                <td>L</td>
                                <td>I</td>
                                <td>N</td>
                                <td>G</td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- Second Row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- Third Row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>I</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>R</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- Forth Row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>N</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>Τ</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>    
                    </table>    
                </div> <!-- end of div.table-->
            </div><!-- end of div.container-->  
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css code:

```
html  {
    font-size:14px ;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed' ;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*TABLE*/

.table {
    text-align: center;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.table > tbody > tr > td{
    padding: 25px; 
}

.table > tbody > tr > td.highlighted {
  background-color:#999;
}
```

Here is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('.table').length){

        var $td = $('.table').find('td');
        var isMouseDown = false;
        var isHighlighted;

        $td.mousedown(function(){ 

            isMouseDown = true;
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
            isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
            return false;

        }).mouseup(function(){

            if (isMouseDown) {
                $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
            }

        }).bind("selectstart", function () {
            return false;
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(){
             isMouseDown = false;
         });            

    }   

});
```

For this I'm using the boostrap, in order to be responsive.
Can you help me out please?

Comment: please provide your html code and related css please. thanks

Comment: @crazymatt - I would have argued that the HTML and CSS were unimportant, and that including the HTML and CSS in the question would only obscure the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't include anything that would select the cells in between.  The only place in your code where a cell could become selected is during the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.  It sounds like your intention is that while the mouse is down, cells that you move the mouse over should become highlighted.  Then do so in a `mouseenter` event handler:

```
$(".table td").mouseenter(function() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
});
```

Try it out here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.table').length) {
    var $td = $('.table').find('td');
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var isHighlighted;

    $td.mousedown(function() {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      return false;
    }).mouseenter(function(){
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      }
    }).mouseup(function() {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
      }
    }).on("selectstart", function() {
      return false;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: navy;
  color: #fff;
}
td {
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
    <td>j</td>
    <td>k</td>
    <td>l</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>m</td>
    <td>n</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>p</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>r</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what if i only want this behaviour  horizontally,means only when i will press and  move my mouse left to right ?

Comment: @Ma6139735 - You could store the row in the `mousedown` handler, then add a condition in your `mouseenter` handler that checks whether this cell is in the same row as the cell in the `mousedown` handler.